# Reading the state from the store in the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building a simple chat application using react and redux. I want to manipulate  only the messages object in the state in the reducer, but i get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined`

This is the reducer:

```
import { getMessages } from "../static_data";
import { SEND_MESSAGE } from "../actions/constants/action_types";
import _ from 'lodash';
import store from '../store';

const { messages } = store.getState();
export default function message(state = messages, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SEND_MESSAGE:
      const { message, userId } = action.payload;
      const allUserMsgs = state[userId];
      const number = +_.keys(allUserMsgs).pop();
      return {
        ...state,
        [userId]: {
          ...allUserMsgs,
          [number]: {
            number,
            text: message,
            is_user_msg: true
          }
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an error in the increment of the number.
I changed this `const number = +_.keys(allUserMsgs).pop();`
To this `const number = _.keys(allUserMsgs).pop() + 1 ;`
and it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Your store setup and/or root reducer file almost definitely import this slice reducer file, so you're creating a circular import problem.  That means that the `store.js` file won't have finished constructing when this module is initialized, so `store` is undefined.

In addition, your reducer logic **should not** be trying to access the store instance.  Instead, it should *only* be determining the new state based on its `(state, action)` arguments.

Also, this slice reducer should define its own initial state value, such as:

```
const initialState = {};

export default function message(state = initialState, action) {
    // logic here
}
```

Comment: Yeah my problem is how i get only the messages object from the state and assign it to the initialState!

Comment: You don't. Your `message()` slice reducer should define its _own_ initial state, like in my example. When you use `combineReducers`, your slice reducers are all responsible for defining their own initial state, and the root state is constructed using those values (because those are returned by the slice reducers).  So, just use my example, and it will work :)  You may also want to read the [Using `combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers) page in the Redux docs.

Comment: I tried it already, the problem it didn't show the old messages and when i write a new message it overrides the previous message.

Comment: Sounds like you may have other problems with your code that go beyond this question. I'd suggest asking over in the Reactiflux chat channels on Discord, at https://reactiflux.com , and showing a larger portion of your code.

Comment: Check my answer